# Meteor: Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty when deploying to Modulus

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, modulus.io

I'm deploying a Meteor app to Modulus.io. I had no problems at all deploying it with `modulus deploy` in the last couple of days but after a couple of changes to my app I now get the following error:

```
Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty
```

It happens at a very late stage of their script, here's the full log from the terminal:

deploy -> v0.10.36
Uploading completed build.
Provisioning and deploying bundle to servos...

fs.js:807
  return binding.rmdir(pathModule._makeLong(path));
                 ^

```
Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/Users/andreaswest/Documents/workspace/test2/.demeteorized'
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.rmdirSync (fs.js:807:18)
at Object.removeSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/modulus/node_modules/fs-tools/lib/fs-tools.js:420:8)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/modulus/lib/controllers/project.js:279:21
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/modulus/lib/controllers/project.js:383:19
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/modulus/lib/controllers/project.js:354:9
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/modulus/lib/librarian/http.js:134:9)
at emitNone (events.js:73:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:167:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:906:12)
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer I got from David Berger from Modulus support:

*Hey Andreas,
Sometimes this will happen and the deploy will have been successful, but the CLI failed to do a little cleanup afterwards.  If your deploy is not working from the CLI, we recommend trying to deploy from the web dashboard: https://my.modulus.io/project/57316
If you deploy from the web dashboard, create a zip of your project files, and then upload it via the ‘deploy files’ upload in the upper right hand corner of the dashboard.*